# Azure blob storage python upload file with client id and secret

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using credentials obtained from App Registration in azure portal.

**Client secrets** is generated, that provides Secret ID and Secret Value.

How can I use this to upload file to blob storage? i cannot find any exisitng python example

Answer (score 0):

If you have client id and secret, first thing you would need to do is create an instance of [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-python) using client id, secret and tenant id. Please note that this is available in [`azure-identity`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) package.

Once you have that, then you can simply use the credentials to create an instance of [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) and then use [`upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob) method to upload the blob.